# Uppercase abbreviated Country in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am using the following code

```
$wpdb->query( "UPDATE $wpdb->usermeta set meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'Ontario', 'ON')" );
```

It works fine, I want to know is there a way I can make the "ON" uppercase in MySQL insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL provides a string function `UPPER()`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_upper

It's possible to reference that function in an INSERT statement.